# how to print dictionary key with first element of nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which value is nested list. for example:

```
d = {1: [[2, 5], [3, 4]]}
```

how can I make link key with first element of nested list and print

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple list comprehension, like this

```
>>> d = {1: [[2, 5], [3, 4]]}
>>> [[key, value[0]] for key in d for value in d[key]]
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

This can be understood, like this

```
>>> result = []
>>> for key in d:
...     for value in d[key]:
...         result.append([key, value[0]])
... 
>>> result
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Or with `dict.items`,

```
>>> result = []
>>> for key, values in d.items():
...     for value in values:
...         result.append([key, value[0]])
...         
>>> result
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

The main idea is, we iterate over the keys of the dictionary with `for key in d` and for every key, we get the value corresponding to it with `d[key]` and iterate the elements of it, to prepare the result in the form `[key, value[0]]`.